# Data gets stored in database from one tab page but it is not shown in another tab page in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am using Visual Studio 2010 which has a form with a **TabControl** containing multiple tab pages.

1st tab page creates employee id and details about the employee which gets stored in the **SQL server** database successfully.
2nd tab page has a ComboBox to display the employee id but it does not show the employee id which was created in the 1st tab page.
When i close the project and run it again it displays the employee id.
How do i rectify this?    Dim OpenDialog As New OpenFileDialog

```
    With OpenDialog
        .Filter = "Image Files (*.gif,*.jpg,*.jpeg,*.bmp,*.png)|*.gif;*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.bmp;*.png"
        .Title = "Select A File"
    End With

    If gender.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        gend = "Male"
    Else
        gend = "Female"

    End If

    If eblood.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        blood = "A +ve"
    ElseIf eblood.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        blood = "A -ve"
    ElseIf eblood.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        blood = "B +ve"
    ElseIf eblood.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        blood = "B -ve"
    ElseIf eblood.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        blood = "AB +ve"
    ElseIf eblood.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        blood = "AB -ve"
    ElseIf eblood.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
        blood = "O +ve"
    Else
        blood = "O -ve"
    End If

    If (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eid.Text.Trim())) Or (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fname.Text.Trim())) Or (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(lname.Text.Trim())) Or (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gender.Text.Trim())) Or (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(gender.Text.Trim())) Or (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(country.Text.Trim())) Or (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eaddress.Text.Trim())) Or (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(equali.Text.Trim())) Or (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(eblood.Text.Trim()) Or (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TextBox_browse.Text.Trim()))) Then

        MsgBox("Please Fill all the Fields", vbExclamation)

    Else

        Dim myconnection As SqlConnection
        Dim mycommand As SqlCommand

        myconnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=billing;Integrated Security=True")
        Try
            myconnection.Open()

            mycommand = New SqlCommand("insert into b_emp_details([ed_id],[ed_first_name],[ed_last_name],[ed_dob],[ed_phone_number],[ed_gender],[ed_joining_date],[ed_country],[ed_address],[ed_qualification],[ed_blood_grp],[ed_image],[ed_created_by],[ed_created_date]) values ('" & eid.Text & "','" & fname.Text & "','" & lname.Text & "','" & dob.Text.ToString & "','" & ph.Text & "','" & gend & "','" & doj.Text.ToString & "','" & country.Text & "','" & eaddress.Text & "','" & equali.Text & "','" & blood & "','" & Trim(TextBox_browse.Text) & "','" & global_user & "','" & global_date & "')", myconnection)
            mycommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
            mycommand.CommandText = "UPDATE b_emp_details SET [ed_image]  ='" & Trim(TextBox_browse.Text) & "' where [ed_id]='" & eid.Text & "'"
            mycommand.Connection = myconnection
            dr = mycommand.ExecuteReader

            Dim newimage As New BitmapImage
            newimage.BeginInit()
            newimage.UriSource = (New Uri(OpenDialog.FileName, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
            TextBox_browse.Text = OpenDialog.FileName
            newimage.EndInit()

            MessageBox.Show("Employee Successfully Created...")
            eid.Text = ""
            fname.Text = ""
            lname.Text = ""
            dob.Text = ""
            ph.Text = ""
            gender.Text = ""
            doj.Text = ""
            country.Text = ""
            eaddress.Text = ""
            equali.Text = ""
            eblood.Text = ""
            TextBox_browse.Text = ""
            Call ResetBindings()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error: " + ex.Message + "Invalid Data..Please Enter A Valid Data....")
            'MsgBox("Invalid Data..Please Enter A Valid Data....")

            myconnection.Close()
        End Try


    End If
```

Comment: Any code which causes you the undesired behavior?

Comment: We have no idea of the DB methods you are using so we can just guess.  In general things like a datatable do not repoll the DB to get AI/PK Ids

Comment: The data gets updated in the database but does not reflect in the combobox of tab2. I have to restart the project to make the value visible.

Comment: There is no ID until you save the data.  If the CBO's datasource was created earlier, you cant expect it to appear.  If the CBO shares the same DAtaSource, you should see the other data appear.  But as in comment #2, whatever the DS is, it doesnt repoll the DB to get that new data (the ID).